# Is 0 a peculiar solution, or not, because of the requirement that $x\neq 0$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the differential equation $xy'+6y=3xy^{\frac{4}{3}}$ and I want to find the solution. I found that $y(x)=\frac{1}{(x+cx^{2})^{3}}, x\in(-\infty,+\infty)-\{0,\frac{-1}{c}\}$.  But is $y=0$ a peculiar solution? Or isn't it because of the fact that $y$ requires that  $x\neq 0$ ?

Comment: Do you mean is $y=0$ a solution? It is.

Comment: Although it is required that $x\neq 0$?

Comment: @evinda: Yes, we need that $x\neq 0$, but what is the definition of a solution? `y=...` or `x=...`? which one?

Comment: @B.S. y should be equal to something..

Comment: Even if the differential equation is singular at $x=0$, there's no reason that a solution should not be defined at $x=0$.

Comment: I understand..thank you all very much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no requirement whatsoever. A classical solution to a differential equation is a $C^1$ function defined on an interval $(a,b)$ such that if we substitute it in the equation we obtain identity.

However, if you want to solve a Cauchy problem with initial data $y(x_0)=y_0$, then we need to write our equation in the form $y'=f(x,y)$. Then again, the Cauchy-Lipchitz theorem (i.e. existence and unicity of solutions) requires that $f(x,y)$ in a  neighbourhood of $(x_0,y_0)$ is continuous  with respect to $x$ and lipchitz with respect to $y$. In your case you can't apply Cauchy-Lipschitz theorem for a problem with initial data in $x=0$. By other arguments, you can say that with initial data $y(0)=0$ you have a solution $y(x)=0$. Note that we don't talk about inicity.

Finally, suppose we have initial data somewhere else. Then your equation might not exist on the whole $\Bbb R$. This explains that in $x=-1/C$ you have a singularity.

Comment: I understand!!Thanks for your answer!!!